# Convert-ToSecureSting ampersand issue powershell

Tags: string, powershell, ampersand, securestring

I have the following code

```
$Password = 'Test&&'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($userName,$securePassword)
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
```

I am unable to connect to my Azure-Account if I set my password having `&` in it. I am not sure does the Convert-To is treating & as any special character.

Setting other special character such as `%` in the password works smoothly for me.

I have tried applying escape characters before `&` in my password but it didn't worked.

Any help would be highly appreciated on this.